# Sort a list with a custom order

Tags: list, python-3.x, intervals

i'd like to sort a list using a custom order, that I have trouble converting into a key (in Python 3 there is no more `sort(L,cmp= ..)`).

I'm ordering intervals : `I_k=[a_k,b_k]`. the order is :

```
I_k>I_l (if a_k>a_l) OR (if a_k=a_l and b_k<=b_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create an interval class with a less than comparison function.

```
class Interval(list):
    __gt__ = __ge__ = __le__ = NotImplemented
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.extend(l)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('help')
        a_l, b_l = self
        a_k, b_k = other
        return a_k>a_l or (a_k==a_l and b_k<=b_l)

L = [[0,1], [2,3], [0,2]]
L = sorted(map(Interval, L))

print(L) # [[0, 2], [0, 1], [2, 3]]
```